# Different Outputs from Solve

Tags: equation-solving, list-manipulation

These commands tell me that y=x^2 doesn't intersect the x-axis. But when I enter this slightly differently the intersection points appear.  What's happening?

This code tells me that y=x^2 doesn't intersect the x-axis.

```
f[x_, a_] = x^2 + a;
sol = Solve[f[x, a] == 0, x, Reals];
Table[{f[x, a], sol}, {a, -4, 4, 4}] // MatrixForm
```

This code shows the double root of f(x)=x^2.

```
f[x_, a_] = x^2 + a;
Table[{f[x, a], Solve[f[x, a] == 0, x, Reals]}, {a, -4, 4, 
   4}] // MatrixForm
```

Comment: Remove `//MatrixForm` and look at the result!

Comment: Don't restrict the domain. Use `sol = Solve[f[x, a] == 0, x];` or use `Reduce` instead of `Solve`

Comment: In the 1st case you first solve for general $a$ and then substitute particular values of $a$. This general solution is correct but incomplete. More solutions can be found with `Reduce`. In the 2nd case, the $a$ parameter is known before hands. Here `Solve` returns all the solutions.

Comment: Thank-you, yarchik for the explanation.

Comment: Thank-you, Bob Hanlon for the suggestion not to restrict the domain.  I need to ignore the non-real solution, but I can do that later by applying the DeleteCases command to my list (table) with _Complex.